# Regex for Validating an Active Directory Object SID

Tags: php, regex, active-directory

I'm looking for a way to validate if an inserted Object SID from Active Directory is valid, is this possible using `preg_match()` or `preg_match_all()`?
I've looked online for a regex for this validation but I couldn't find anything.

Example:

```
$sid = 'S-1-5-21-1220945662-1202665555-839525555-5555';

if ($validator->validateSid($sid)) {
    // SID is valid!
}
```

I'm not skilled in writing regex's, so if anyone has absolutely any input, please let me know, thanks!

EDIT: For anyone looking for the code with the regex below:

```
preg_match("/^S-1-[0-5]-\d{2}-\d{10}-\d{10}-\d{9}-[1-9]\d{3}/", $search, $matches);

// Returns
array(
    0 => S-1-5-21-1220945662-1202665555-839525555-5555
)
```

Or for a more lenient pattern:

```
preg_match("/S-1-5-21-\d+-\d+\-\d+\-\d+/", $sid, $matches);

// Returns
array(
    0 => S-1-5-21-1220945662-1202665555-839525555-5555
)
```

Comment: What are the rules?  Is it always `S-something`?  Are the digits between `-` constrained to a certain number of digits?

Comment: I know it's been a lot of years, but your "lenient" pattern worked for me where the accepted answer did not, because several of the SIDs I'm working with end in 4, 5, and even some with 6 digits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hjpotter92's answer will work for some SID's but not all.
Each subauthority is comprised of a 32-bit integer, which can be 10 digits or 8 digits depending. You should edit the regex to be:

```
/^S-1-[0-59]-\d{2}-\d{8,10}-\d{8,10}-\d{8,10}-[1-9]\d{3}/
```

> Whenever a new issuing authority under Windows is created (for
> example, a new machine deployed or a domain created), it is assigned a
> SID with 5 (an arbitrary value) as the identifier authority; a fixed
> value of 21 is used as a unique value to root this set of
> subauthorities, and a **96-bit random number is created and parceled out
> to the three subauthorities with each subauthority that receives a
> 32-bit chunk.**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc246018.aspx

[How SIDs are created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXntk.png)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [wiki for SID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier), the following should work:

```
/^S-1-[0-59]-\d{2}-\d{10}-\d{10}-\d{8}-[1-9]\d{3}/
```

Answer (score 0):

The last section of the SID is the RID which is a 32 bit identifier! It means RID can have 10 digits. So the last section can be even 1 + 9 digits long in theory! ;)

```
S-1-[0-59]-\d{2}-\d{10}-\d{10}-\d{8}-[1-9]\d{9}
```