# How to find if Powershell Array Contain part of another Array

Tags: arrays, powershell, compare

I have 2 Arrays

```
$Array1 = Get-Disabledusers SIDS
$Array2 =  %Unnecessarytext(SIDS).VHDX
```

I need to compare `Array1` and `Array2` and output only the things in `Array2` that contain `Array1`.
Thing is, when I compare both objects, it returns not equal because they don't match exactly.

How do I get it to output the items in Array2 that contain the matching Disabled Users SIDS?
Should I run a foreach loop and compare a part of the Array?

I found this: [How to find if Powershell Array Contains Object of Another Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45596358/how-to-find-if-powershell-array-contains-object-of-another-array)

However this doesn't help as it will return not equal.

**Clarified Question:**

There is a folder in which there are VHDXs. The VHDXs are named based on a user's SID. However, there is a bunch if unnecessary text before and after the SIDs.

In Array1, I run:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $false} | FT SID
```

In order to retrieve a list of disabled users and filter out their SIDs.

In Array2, I list the names of the files in the VHDX folder which look like this: `text SID text`. I want to compare both and return which files in the VHDX folders contain the SIDS of the disabled users.

Comment: Are the arrays just value SIDs or are those objects with more properties? Also what have you tried?

Comment: `#Get A list of Disabled Users SID's and store them in an array
$DisabledSIDS = Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $false} | FT SID

#Get a list of current VHDXS and  store them in an array
$VHDXNames = (Get-ChildItem -Path Path | FT Name)`


I've tried outputting them all to text files then re-importing while getting rid of the extra values. But was told that that was war crime level of spaghetti code.
I can't remember the previous other tries that I've done. Will update if I remember

Comment: So you have folders which's name are SIDs ? If so, can you edit your question adding this information as well as the code you've tried to it so other readers can see it ? It would be nice to understand if the names of the folder are following the naming convention of an actual SID too

Comment: Ok, sorry if my question is vague. I'll update it.

There is a folder in which there are VHDXs. 
The VHDXs are named based on a user's SID. 
However, there is a bunch if unecessary text before and after the SIDs.
in Array1, I run `Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $false} | FT SID` in order to retrieve a list of disabled users and filter out their SIDs.

In Array2, I list the names of the files in the VHDX folder which look like this: *text* SID *text*.

I want to compare both and return which files in the VHDX folders contain the SIDS of the disabled users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way, first get the list of SID values from all disabled users and store them in a variable, then since the files or folders (unclear on this) are not exact SIDs, you will need to first check if they contain a valid SID, this can be accomplished using a [regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.2) and the [`-match` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#matching-operators) and if they do, then we can use the [automatic variable `$Matches`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#matches) to check if the SID is [`-in`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#containment-operators) the array of SIDs of Disabled Users, if yes, we can output that file or folder and store it in `$result`:

```
$re = 'S-1-[0-59]-\d{2}-\d{8,10}-\d{8,10}-\d{8,10}-[1-9]\d{2,3}'
$sids = (Get-ADUser -Filter "Enabled -eq '$false'").SID.Value
$result = foreach($item in Get-ChildItem -Path path\to\something) {
    if($item.Name -match $re) {
        if($Matches[0] -in $sids) {
            $item
        }
    }
}

$result # => has all the files or folders existing in `$sids`
```

The regex used was taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52284643/15339544) and only required to change the last `\d{3}` for `\d{2,3}` to match any valid SID.